# Efficient way to iterate python loop until previous position

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list `a` and I need to iterate from position 2 until its previous position 1.

```
# old index - 0 1 2 3 4

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

# new index - 2,3,4,0,1
# new value - 3,4,5,1,2
cnt = 0 
while True:
    for i in range(2,len(a)):
        print(a[i])

    for i in range(len(a)-2-1):
        print(a[i])

    break
```

I'm using 2 for loops but I believe there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: What happened to `5`? EDIT: your edit has confused things because we also have a `0` in one example and not another.

Comment: Using NumPy might be overkill but what you want is exactly what `np.roll(a, -2)` gives you provided you convert `a` to an array.

Comment: @roganjosh: One is index and another one is value, its mentioned explicitly..

Comment: If you want skip importing numpy and if the index is fixed you could also do `a[2::]+a[0:2:]` to give the index you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we start with a list `a = [1,2,3,4,5]`.

You can use `collections.deque` and its method `deque.rotate`:

```
from collections import deque

b = deque(a)
b.rotate(-2)

print(b)

deque([3, 4, 5, 1, 2])
```

Or, if you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use NumPy and `np.roll`:

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array(a)
c = np.roll(c, -2)

print(c)

array([3, 4, 5, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Why write first `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` and then `a = np.array(a)`? Why not `a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`?

Comment: I'm assuming they are starting from a list (as in their question). I can take those lines out if they help you.

Comment: Nah, was just curious if there is some hidden benefit I am not aware of :)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new list combining the elements after the particular value and before the particular value, let's say `3` in your case:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
piv = a.index(3)
print(a[piv:] + a[:piv])
```

which gives you `[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

A base python based solution

```
a[2::] + a[:2:]
```

Gives

```
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

A generic version of the same would be

```
rotate_from = 2
a[rotate_from::] + a[:rotate_from:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

position = 2
for item in a[position:] + a[:position]:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function for rotate list,

```
In [114]: def rotate(lst, n):
     ...:     return lst[-n:] + lst[:-n]
     ...: 

In [115]: rotate(a,-2)
Out[115]: [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```